# Different precisions in predicting two classes with logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, python, scikit-learn

I am using the kaggle's stroke dataset trying to predict the `stroke` target feature, according to multiple predictive features. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset

The stroke feature has either `1` or `0`, so it's great for classification purposes.

I am using logistic regression with the sklearn library. the problem with this dataset is that it is unbalanced. There is approximatly 210 stroke cases (`stroke = 1`) and 4000 no stroke (`stroke = 0`).

###### Here is my code:

```
X = data_Enco.iloc[:, data_Enco.columns != 'stroke'].values  # features
Y = data_Enco.iloc[:, 6]  # labels

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)  

logisticModel = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
logisticModel.fit(X_train, Y_train) # Train the model
predictions_log = logisticModel.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(Y_test, predictions_log))
```

Check out the confusion matrix:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0       0.99      0.66      0.79       935
     1       0.11      0.83      0.19        47

accuracy                        0.66       982
macro avg      0.55    0.74     0.49       982
weighted avg   0.95    0.66     0.76       982
```

The precision is pretty bad for stroke = 1.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LogisticRegression.predict_proba()` to extract the predicted probabilities. Then compare them to a different threshold than the 0.5 that is inexplicably built into `LogisticRegression.predict()`. Tweak the threshold until you get a precision you are happy with. I very, very much recommend [Reduce Classification Probability Threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).

Note that precision is a highly problematic evaluation metric for all the same reasons [accuracy is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

You may also be interested in [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352).

Comment: Thank you sir. Any chance you're familiar with a tutorial that handles this kind of problem using python? I'm having a bit of trouble with the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, sorry, no.